# google maps v2 app launched but no map`s loaded

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, maps

I'm developing a simple Google Maps v2 app. I followed some tutorials from androidhive.info, etc. The tutorials work perfectly for them, but not for me.

**androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="artsofdevelopements.org.admaps" >

<permission
    android:name="artsofdevelopements.org.admaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="artsofdevelopements.org.admaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Goolge API Key -->
    <meta-data
            android:name="artsofdevelopements.org.admaps.AIzaSyD66Am2aXhahzwPMKqLV94O7HLIXnG8EPI"
        android:value="AIzaSyD66Am2aXhahzwPMKqLV94O7HLIXnG8EPI" />
</application>
```

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ArtsOfDevelopements.org.ADMaps"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['google-play-services.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

**mapsactivity.java**

```
package artsofdevelopements.org.admaps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

class Maps extends FragmentActivity {
GoogleMap map;
double lat;
double lan;
boolean flag = false;

// private LocationManager lm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}
}
```

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The application is compiled and launches on my device normally, but the thing is all I see is the zoom buttons and the google sign. No map

Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: That would happen if you have not signed the application properly. Go back to the Google maps API and check if you have signed it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I see this problem in your manifest too though change the name in meta-data as the following and use your own API key.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/maps_v2_API_KEY" />

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: in the android:value .. should i paste too my api key ?

Comment: Yes instead of puting in your strings folder like i did you can just paste it over here.

Comment: the api key is correct i just checked .. i`ll test now and get back to you sir :)

Comment: same thing bro :( nothing just the zoom buttons and the google sign .. pleaaase heeelp

Comment: Check and see if you have installed google play services and see my updated answer

Comment: try testing the application on real device over an emulator because i remember you have to do some special steps to make the maps work on an emulator.

Comment: i already did on a device quad core processor and 1.2 gigs on ram

Comment: it`s working nooow .. i just re do the whole app from the begining i deleted my original and re do the stuff with android studio from 0 .. and now it`s working sooo well :) thank you all .. thank you soooo much